# How can I verify that webpack has built my blob with NODE_ENV=production?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to check whether, on any arbitrary site, they have built their javascript blob with NODE_ENV=production?

For example, to work out what jQuery version a site is using I would type into console `$.fn.jquery`.

Is there anything I can type into console to see if the javascript blob was built with NODE_ENV=production?